# ¿Como monto una aplicación java en un servidor centOS?

Tags: java, centos

Tengo un servidor en centOS y quiero probar una aplicación desarrollada en java, me gustaría subirla, saber si se puede y ¿qué pasos debo realizar?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a un servidor escrito en Java o un servlet, jsp o ejb que quieres desplegar en un servidor de aplicaciones Java instalado en la máquina? No queda claro en tu pregunta. En caso de que sea lo último, ¿qué servidor de aplicaciones quieres usar o conoces? Te dejo [**un enlace**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_de_aplicaciones#Servidores_de_aplicaci.C3.B3n_Java_EE) para que decidas en este último caso cuál podría venirte mejor.

Comment: Hola Oscar gracias por responderme, mira es que tengo una aplicación desarrollada en java con extensiones de todo los archivos en .java y tenemos un servidor en centOS y queremos dejarla instalada , ya que esta aplicación esta desarrollada para aplicarla en consola

Comment: Bien, entonces requieres dos cosas: a) instalar JRE b) configurar un servicio que arranque al inicio y puedas controlar su inicio y parada. ¿Cierto? ¿Qué versión de CentOS tienes y qué versión de Java quieres usar?

Comment: Por favor @Esteban, debes modificar tu pregunta indicando los detalles que me has facilitado para poder abrir la pregunta de nuevo.

Comment: No me dejo en centOS correrla ya que necesito una .dll de windows para que corra (win32.dll) y con eso solucionaría pero, lo otro que estaba leyendo que es hacerlo correr con wine en linux para que funcione

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que es una aplicación normal escrita en Java y que tienes acceso al código fuente, lo que necesitas hacer es:

- Instalar en la máquina donde se va a ejecutar esta aplicación un entorno de ejecución de Java (Java Runtime Environment o JRE).
- Crear un Jar ejecutable de la aplicación, por ejemplo siguiendo los pasos [descritos aquí](http://es.wikihow.com/crear-un-archivo-ejecutable-en-Eclipse).
- Copiar dicho jar a la máquina donde quieras ejecutarlo.
- Ejecutarlo desde la línea de comando:

  `java -jar <nombre_del_fichero.jar> [parámetros que hagan falta]`

Como he dicho, esto es asumiendo que es una aplicación Java común, no una aplicación J2EE que requiera un contenedor de aplicaciones tipo Tomcat o similares, en cuyo caso necesitas instalar dicho contenedor y hacer un despliegue de la aplicación, además de asegurarte de que cualquier dependencia está cubierta (base de datos, ficheros de configuración... etc)